# Bash difference in file

Tags: file, bash, sum

I would like to write a bash code in order two compare different files in the following way.
When the value of the first five column are equal in both file, sum the value of the remaining column in the two different file together(e.g. colum6file1+colum6file2,etc). When they are different just keep both of the different line in the new file. 
Notice that i cannot compare line by line because a line at the beginning of the first file can have the same four column value of a line at the end of the second file.

Hope this is clear,

Thanks.

File1:

```
  118    2   AA      4.25     30.25  1  
  119    2   AA      4.50     30.25  2  
  120    2   AA      4.75     30.25  3  
  121    2   AA      5.00     30.25  4  
  122    2   AA      5.25     30.25  5  
  123    2   AA      5.50     30.25  6    
  124    2   AA      5.75     30.25  7   
  125    2   AA      6.00     30.25  8    
  126    2   AA      6.25     30.25  9
```

File2:

```
  179    1   BB     19.75     30.00  1  
  180    1   BB     19.75     30.00  2  
  230    1   BB     32.25     30.00  3   
  231    1   BB     32.50     30.00  4      
  232    1   BB     32.75     30.00  5   
  118    2   AA      4.25     30.25  6   
  119    2   AA      4.50     30.25  7  
  120    2   AA      5.00     30.25  8   
  121    2   AA      5.00     30.25  9
```

Output:

```
  118    2   AA      4.25     30.25  7    
  119    2   AA      4.50     30.25  9    
  120    2   AA      4.75     30.25  11    
  121    2   AA      5.00     30.25  13    
  122    2   AA      5.25     30.25  5  
  123    2   AA      5.50     30.25  6    
  124    2   AA      5.75     30.25  7   
  125    2   AA      6.00     30.25  8    
  126    2   AA      6.25     30.25  9  
  179    1   BB     19.50     30.00  1    
  180    1   BB     19.75     30.00  2  
  230    1   BB     32.25     30.00  3   
  231    1   BB     32.50     30.00  4      
  232    1   BB     32.75     30.00  5
```

Comment: please provide sample input and output

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing exactly what your input files look like, but this sounds like something that might be rather difficult in bash alone.  A more feature-complete language like Ruby or Python would most likely allow for an easier solution, if that's an option.

Comment: You're likely to need to sort both the files.  You're problem is under-specified. For instance, you've not indicated whether a single row in file 1 is allowed to be associated with multiple rows in file 2 (that have the same first four columns) and vice versa, or whether each line in each file can only be used at most once.

Comment: No, a single line cannot be associated with multiple rows in file 2 (that have the same first five columns) due to data structure. A file with five (correction not 4) equal value it will present just one time in a file.

Comment: Is the order of the lines in the file (input or output) significant?  That is, can the lines be sorted or re-ordered without breaking anything?  What about the amount of whitespace between entries?

Comment: No, the order of the lines is not significant. The amount of space between the columns entries varies just for an aesthetic purpose. But can be rearranged.

Comment: Can one of the input data files contain two records which differ only in the 6th field?  Judging from the example data, the first column is unique in each file, so that duplicate entries are not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can likely be minimized, but here's a rough cut at a solution to what I *think* is the question:

```
sort file1 file2 |
  awk '{current = sprintf("%s %s %s %s %s", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5)

      if (current == previous) {
        total = total + $6
      } else if (previous) {
        printf("%s %d\n", previous, total)
        total = $6
      } else {
        total = $6
      }

      previous = current
    }
    END { printf("%s %d\n", previous, total) }'
```

Comment: Maybe I forget to say that the format of the value to sum are like this: 0.00000E+00 and I will need to repeat it until column 16. I'm testing it right now.

Comment: You're in luck. Awk will parse that format just fine. I'm not sure what you mean by repeating until column 16.

Comment: @Rob Davis. This is working really well. But still when the sums are made the format is no longer  0.00000E+0 but just 0.00.... Any idea?

Comment: If someone is interested I found it. Just replace `%d` with `%e`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sed` command to get only the first column, and then compare it.

[sed tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-8)

so: `sed -e "s/([0-9]*\)\s.*/\1/"`

will get the first number (separated from other by `\s` — whitespace character)
basically it looks like `s/match pattern/replacement/`.

You use `/( /)` to mark occurrence of some text, or pattern and `\<number>` to use it in replace string. As the replacement string, I used `\1` as it is first (and the only one) marked fragment.

As I used here: I found first number (`[0-9]*`) and marked it, separated by whitespace (`\s`) and to replace the rest of line I put `.*`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please note that people do not use SMS-style abbreviations in either questions or answers.  Please write in full sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution.  I'm not sure whether it is elegant or awful.  It exploits the `join` command (and therefore also the `sort` command), plus `awk`.

```
file1=xx1
file2=xx2

join -t ' ' -j 1  -a 1 -a 2 -o 1.1,2.1,1.2,2.2 \
    <(sort -b $file1 | awk '{printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s %s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6)}') \
    <(sort -b $file2 | awk '{printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s %s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6)}') |
awk '{
    if (NF == 6) sum = $6;
    else         sum = $11 + $12;
    print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, sum;
}'
```

The file names are parameters.  The `<(sort -b $fileN | awk '...')` is 'process substitution', a distinctive feature of `bash`.  It means 'run the commands inside the parentheses, and the standard output of the pipeline is provided as a named file (usually `/dev/fd/NN`) to the command, in this case, `join`.  The pipelines are devious; they sort the data, and then `awk` formats the data so that the key fields (the first 5 fields) are separated by tabs, but the sixth field is separated from them by a blank.  The `sort -b` ignores leading blanks in fields; it is crucial to getting sane results.

The `join` command treats a blank as the field separator (`-t ' '`), so the input files each have two fields as far as `join` is concerned.  The join occurs on equality of the first field `-j 1` (remembering that the first field is the set of 5 tab-separated values).  The output includes unmatched entries from file 1 (`-a 1`) and file 2 (`-a 2`).  The output format is field 1 from file 1, field 1 from file 2, field 2 from file 1, and field 2 from file 2.

If there's a match, then the output will have a dozen blank-or-tab separated columns.
If there's no match, then the output will have half-a-dozen blank-or-tab separated columns.

The post-processing in `awk` exploits the fact that blanks and tabs are both field separators to `awk`.  If the input line has 6 fields, there was no match for that key, so the sum is the value in `$6`.  If the input line has any other number of fields (it should be 12), then the sum is the value of the last two fields, `$11 + $12`.  The script then prints out the first five fields, plus the sum.

This trickery with blanks vs tabs as field separators is probably grotesque, but in this context it is fairly effective.

Since there is a most one line in each file with a given key (the first five columns are unique in each file) in the sample data, the fact that `join` will pair N lines from file 1 with M lines from file 2 to give NxM output lines doesn't matter since N = 1 and M = 1 as desired.

#### Example output

Given the data files shown in the question (and the script in a file `jb.sh`):

```
$ bash jb.sh
118 2 AA 4.25 30.25 7
119 2 AA 4.50 30.25 9
120 2 AA 4.75 30.25 3
120 2 AA 5.00 30.25 8
121 2 AA 5.00 30.25 13
122 2 AA 5.25 30.25 5
123 2 AA 5.50 30.25 6
124 2 AA 5.75 30.25 7
125 2 AA 6.00 30.25 8
126 2 AA 6.25 30.25 9
179 1 BB 19.75 30.00 1
180 1 BB 19.75 30.00 2
230 1 BB 32.25 30.00 3
231 1 BB 32.50 30.00 4
232 1 BB 32.75 30.00 5
$
```

I note that this output is not identical to the desired output, but that's because the desired output is erroneous for the given inputs (or the inputs are erroneous for the desired output).  The sample data has the lines:

```
120 2   AA  4.75    30.25  3 
120 2   AA  5.00    30.25  8
```

Note that column 4 is not the same here (4.75 vs 5.00), so those lines cannot be combined and you get two output lines for '120'.

---

### Extending to 16 columns

The script has minor tidying up, and otherwise continues the same pattern as before:

```
file1=xx1
file2=xx2

sort_print()
{
    sort -b "$@" |
    awk '{printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s %s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n",
                 $1,$2,$3,$4,$5, $6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16)}'
}

join -t ' ' -j 1  -a 1 -a 2 -o 1.1,2.1,1.2,2.2 \
    <(sort_print $file1) <(sort_print $file2) |
tee joined.data |
awk '{
    if (NF != 16)
    {
        for (i = 6; i <= 16; i++)
        {
            j = i + 16
            $i = $i + $j;
        }
    }
    printf "%s %s %s %s %s", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5;
    for (i = 6; i <= 16; i++)
        printf " %s", $i;
    printf "\n";
}'
```

#### File xx1

```
118    2   AA      4.25     30.25  1  2 3 4 5 14 5 4 5 7 8
119    2   AA      4.50     30.25  2  2 3 4 5 4 15 4 5 7 8
120    2   AA      5.00     30.25  3  2 3 4 5 4 5 14 5 7 8
121    2   AA      5.00     30.25  4  2 3 4 5 4 5 4 15 7 8
122    2   AA      5.25     30.25  5  2 3 4 5 4 5 4 5 17 8
123    2   AA      5.50     30.25  6    2 13 4 5 4 5 4 5 7 18
124    2   AA      5.75     30.25  7   2 3 4 5 4 5 4 5 7 18
125    2   AA      6.00     30.25  8    12 3 4 5 4 5 4 5 7 18
126    2   AA      6.25     30.25  9  2 3 4 5 4 5 4 5 7 18
```

#### File xx2

```
179    1   BB     19.75     30.00  1   8 21 2 4 12 2 3 1 9 1032
180    1   BB     19.75     30.00  2  29 1 22 4 12 2 3 1 9 1042
230    1   BB     32.25     30.00  3   9 8 2 44 12 2 3 1 9 1052
231    1   BB     32.50     30.00  4   9 17 2 44 12 2 3 1 9 1062
232    1   BB     32.75     30.00  5   9 8 1 4 122 2 3 1 9 1072
118    2   AA      4.25     30.25  6   9 8 1 2 4 22 3 1 9 1082
119    2   AA      4.50     30.25  7  29 8 1 2 4 12 23 1 9 1092
120    2   AA      5.00     30.25  8   9 8 1 2 4 12 2 21 9 1002
121    2   AA      5.00     30.25  9   9 8 1 2 4 12 2 3 29 1012
```

#### Output

```
118 2 AA 4.25 30.25 124 11 8 5.25 32.25 5 24 6 5 14 1096
119 2 AA 4.50 30.25 126 31 8 5.5 32.25 6 14 26 5 14 1096
120 2 AA 5.00 30.25 128 11 8 6 32.25 7 14 5 25 14 1006
121 2 AA 5.00 30.25 130 11 8 6 32.25 8 14 5 7 34 1016
122 2 AA 5.25 30.25 5 2 3 4 5 4 5 4 5 17 8
123 2 AA 5.50 30.25 6 2 13 4 5 4 5 4 5 7 18
124 2 AA 5.75 30.25 7 2 3 4 5 4 5 4 5 7 18
125 2 AA 6.00 30.25 8 12 3 4 5 4 5 4 5 7 18
126 2 AA 6.25 30.25 9 2 3 4 5 4 5 4 5 7 18
179 1 BB 19.75 30.00 1 8 21 2 4 12 2 3 1 9 1032
180 1 BB 19.75 30.00 2 29 1 22 4 12 2 3 1 9 1042
230 1 BB 32.25 30.00 3 9 8 2 44 12 2 3 1 9 1052
231 1 BB 32.50 30.00 4 9 17 2 44 12 2 3 1 9 1062
232 1 BB 32.75 30.00 5 9 8 1 4 122 2 3 1 9 1072
```

Comment: You are right sorry. The output is erroneous and you should get two lines for '120' as you suggest. What about if in the same file I also need to report the sum of the other column (colum7file1+colum7file2;colum8file1+colum8file2;...until column 16.

Comment: That, my friend, is called an "exercise for the reader"! It is not trivial, though.  It was messy enough getting this right.  Most likely, for your columns 7-16 version, you need to go to Perl or Python.  There's more than enough subtlety in the shell above.

Comment: If the  the files are `;` separated will this change a lot the code?. So for example 179;1;BB;19.75;30.00;1. In this case what I will need to change? Thanks

Comment: You don't earn people's undying gratitude or willingness to help by unaccepting their answer (without even a compensatory upvote) and then asking a subsidiary question which doesn't really exercise the brain cells.  If the input data is separated by semicolons instead of blanks and tabs, it requires an extra option to `awk` in the function.  If the output data is separated by semicolons instead of blanks, then you need to replace the printed blanks in the final `awk` script with semicolons.